# Native camera crash after camera.release() or else

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I experience weird phone *freeze/crash/gray camera screen* while opening camera intent. I am not able to reproduce this error regularly, but it happens several times a day on one of my test devices (*Huawei Ascend P6*), but there is no determinate sequence of steps that cause crash.

Also in even rarer occasions, making photo on this device while in intent from my app causes phone to restart. This behavior isn't a problem in other apps that use camera intent, so I suppose it's something wrong with my code.

My code for opening camera intent:

```
public void openCameraForPhoto(OpenCameraForPhotoEvent event) {
        photoUri = null;
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                showErrorToastAndFinish(errorMessage);
            }

            if (photoFile != null) {
                photoUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        photoUri);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }
```

There are several suspects that, I assume, may cause this unpredictable behavior.

**First of all**, I use *TextureView* to show camera preview on a screen from which I launch camera intent. Although I do camera.release() in onPause method, I suppose it may not get called occasionally.

**Secondary**, I use another *TextureView* to display some video on the same screen. Since I use *MediaPlayer* to do that, maybe it clashes with camera, causing it to act weird? Does *MediaPlayer* have anything to do with camera launching? Maybe there are images loading from gallery in background or something like that?

**Third** and least suspicious thing I do: open camera intent from newly created activity. I don't really think that is the reason of such behavior, but maybe device cannot handle CPU or memory spike.

So, the question is: **what can I do to prevent this behavior**, that is not indicated by any errors or exceptions, but makes app usage unsatisfactory?

Comment: THere's nothing wrong with your code, but if you're showing a camera preview and then launching a camera intent, you may have issues if you still own the camera.  If you're showing the preview, you really ought to take the picture yourself via the Camera2 api rather than via intent.

Comment: Since I want to support devices starting from 15 api, at first I was using old Camera api, but it caused a lot of crashes too. So I decided to switch to more safe approach - with using camera intent. And it works really great on most devices, and will have less problems in future support. 
I'd like to know, if there a way to ensure that my device doesn't own camera before starting an intent?